# Opening an EXE of my python program gives me ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler

Tags: python, pyqt4

I use pyqt4 to write a program to get some data from website and save as json

```
 import json
 import sys
 from PyQt4 import QtGui
 from PyQt4 import QtCore
 from pip._vendor.requests import RequestException
 import requests  
 ...
 content_debt = requests.get(debt_url+self.name)
 debt_str= content_debt.text
 debtf = open(self.name+".json",'wb')
 debtf.write(debt_str)
 debtf.close()

 content_ind = requests.get(ind_url+self.name)
 ind_str = content_ind.text
 indf = open(self.name+".json",'wb')
 indf.write(ind_str)
 indf.close()
```

run well,so I tried to put it into an exe by py2exe

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

#this allows to run it with a simple double click.
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

py2exe_options = {
    "includes": ["sip"],
    "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll",],
    "compressed": 1,
    "optimize": 2,
    "ascii": 0,
    "bundle_files": 1
    }

setup(
  name = 'Search',
  version = '1.0',
  windows = ['main.py',], 
  zipfile = None,
  options = {'py2exe': py2exe_options}
  )
```

open the main.exe,In my computer it do well,but another computer get a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "pip\__init__.pyo", line 15, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "pip\vcs\subversion.pyo", line 9, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "pip\index.pyo", line 30, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "pip\wheel.pyo", line 35, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.pyo", line 14, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "pip\_vendor\distlib\compat.pyo", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: please looke here: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/TroubleshootingImportErrors